# find data between two dates in Mongodb + php

Tags: php, mongodb, date, range

my collection structure is

`"classStartDate" : ISODate("2018-04-26T00:00:00.000Z")` in mongo db,

now I am searching record between   2018-01-01 to 2018-07-31, 
My code is

```
$where = array( "classStartDate"    => array('$gte'=>$mongostartdate), "classEndDate"      => array('$lte'=>$mongoenddate));
```

but no result found, Pls help

Comment: Try this `$pipeline = array(
    'classStartDate' => array(
        '$lte' => new MongoDate('2018-07-31'),
        '$gte' => new MongoDate('2018-01-01')
     )
   )
);`

Answer (score 0):

```
CollectionName.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte:$mongostartdate,
        $lt: mongoenddate
    }
})
```